# C++: glibc detected corrupted double-linked list: 0x08f8f148

Tags: c++, glibc, corrupt

I'm writing a program which needs to parse the PATH environment variable at a delimiter ":". Everything seems to be working properly until function chop tries to return the array. I then receive the following error:  "glibc detected  ./a.out: corrupted double-linked list: 0x08f8f148". I use the chop to also parse user input and it works properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
//Parse environment variable
    char const* pPath = getenv("PATH");
    if (pPath == NULL){;}
    else{
        string ePath(pPath);
        envp = chop(ePath,':');
    }

char **chop(string s, char c){
    int i, j, k, len, words = 0;
    len = s.length();
    //determine # of words
    for(i=0;i<len+1;i++){
        if(s[i] == c || s[i] == '\0'){words++;}
    }
    char **array;
    string x;
    //allocate memory for char pointers
    if((array=(char**)malloc((words+1)*sizeof(char*))) == NULL){return NULL;}
    array[0] = &x[0];
    i = 0; k = 0;
    //split string on char c
    for(j = 1; j < (words+1); j++,k++,i++){
        //read in characters until delimiter
        while (s[k] != c && s[k] != '\0'){

            x[i] = s[k];
            i++; k++;
        }
        x[i] = '\0';
        array[j] = &x[i+1];
    }
    array[j] = 0;
    return array;   
}
```

Comment: The error is not in the code that you have shown. Most likely you are deleting something twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a glibc free/malloc/realloc invalid next size/invalid pointer error and how to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680334/what-is-a-glibc-free-malloc-realloc-invalid-next-size-invalid-pointer-error-and)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you have noticed this or not, but you are creating an array of pointers to locations within a `std::string` object `x` that has function-local scope. As soon as this function returns, those pointers are not guaranteed to be meaningful, because `x` will be destroyed.

You are allocating persistent storage for the array of pointers for chopped words, but failing to ensure that what they point to has a life-span longer than the function itself. If you reference any of these pointers it will be undefined behavior, which *just* might be the cause of your linked-list corruption.

Even if it is not the cause of your problem, this is still an error that needs to be addressed. It almost looks like you adapted a C-based `chop (...)` function that operated on `char *` and replaced it with `std::string` not realizing what happens when a string object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error in some code where someone was calling exit() in one thread about the same time as `main()` returned, causing global/static constructors to run in both threads.

This error also manifests as `double free or corruption`, a segfault/sig11 inside `exit()` or inside `malloc_consolidate`, and likely others.

The problem never showed up when running under valgrind.